# R using data.table to calculate a column dependent on previous rows

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, data.table, rcpp

I have multiple products with associated daily sales. I want to forecast the expected daily sales of these products based on a running cumulative sales for each product and the total I expect to sell over a period of time.

The first table ("key") has the Total Sales expected for each product, as well as how much I am forecasting to sell each day based on how much has already been sold (i.e. if my cumulative sales for Product A is 650, I have sold 43% of the 1500 total, and would therefore forecast to sell 75 the next day because 40% <= 43% < 60%).

I want to update the second table ("data") cumulative sales for each product based on the forecasted sales volumes. The forecasted volumes depend on the cumulative sales for the prior period, meaning I can’t calculate each column independently and thus I think I need to use loops.

However my database has over 500,000 rows and my best attempt at using for loops is too slow to be feasible. Thoughts? I think Rcpp implementation could be a potential solution, but I have not used that package or C++ before. The desired final answer is shown below ("final").

```
library(data.table)
key <- data.table(Product = c(rep("A",5), rep("B",5)), TotalSales = 
c(rep(1500,5),rep(750,5)), Percent = rep(seq(0.2, 1, 0.2),2), Forecast = 
c(seq(125, 25, -25), seq(75, 15, -15)))

data <- data.table(Date = rep(seq(1, 9, 1), 2), Product=rep(c("A", "B"), 
each=9L), Time = rep(c(rep("Past",4), rep("Future",5)),2), Sales = c(190, 
165, 133, 120, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 72, 58, 63, 51, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))

final <- data.table(data, Cum = c(190, 355, 488, 608, 683, 758, 833, 908, 
958, 72, 130, 193, 244, 304, 349, 394, 439, 484), Percent.Actual = c(0.13, 
0.24, 0.33, 0.41, 0.46, 0.51, 0.56, 0.61, 0.64, 0.10, 0.17, 0.26, 0.33, 
0.41, 0.47, 0.53, 0.59, 0.65), Forecast = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 75, 75, 75, 75, 50, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 60, 45, 45, 45, 45))
```

Comment: Why `Cum` values re-started from 10th row?

Comment: Please edit for avoiding the "wall of text" impression.

Comment: I think your data and final tables are missing a Product column that would answer @MKR 's question.

Comment: The "final" table merges in the previously-built "data" table, which has a Product column. The "Cum" column resets per Product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is really going to help with your actual dataset given the size.

```
library(data.table)

#convert key into a list for fast loookup
keyLs <- lapply(split(key, by="Product"), 
    function(x) list(TotalSales=x[,TotalSales[1L]], 
                     Percent=x[,Percent], 
                     Forecast=x[,Forecast]))

#for each product, use recursion to calculate cumulative sales after finding the forecasted sales
futureSales <- data[, {
        byChar <- as.character(.BY)
        list(Date=Date[Time=="Future"], 
            Cum=Reduce(function(x, y) {
                pct <- x / keyLs[[byChar]]$TotalSales
                res <- x + keyLs[[byChar]]$Forecast[findInterval(pct, c(0, keyLs[[byChar]]$Percent))]
                if (res >= keyLs[[byChar]]$TotalSales) return(keyLs[[byChar]]$TotalSales)
                res
            },
            x=rep(0L, sum(Time=="Future")),
            init=sum(Sales[Time=="Past"]),
            accumulate=TRUE)[-1])
    },
    by=.(Product)]
futureSales 

#calculate other sales stats
futureSales[data, on=.(Date, Product)][,
    Cum := ifelse(is.na(Cum), cumsum(Sales), Cum),
    by=.(Product)][,
        ':=' (
            Percent.Actual = Cum / keyLs[[as.character(.BY)]]$TotalSales,
            Forecast = ifelse(Sales > 0, 0, c(0, diff(Cum)))
        ), by=.(Product)][]
#     Product Date Cum   Time Sales Percent.Actual Forecast
#  1:       A    1 190   Past   190      0.1266667        0
#  2:       A    2 355   Past   165      0.2366667        0
#  3:       A    3 488   Past   133      0.3253333        0
#  4:       A    4 608   Past   120      0.4053333        0
#  5:       A    5 683 Future     0      0.4553333       75
#  6:       A    6 758 Future     0      0.5053333       75
#  7:       A    7 833 Future     0      0.5553333       75
#  8:       A    8 908 Future     0      0.6053333       75
#  9:       A    9 958 Future     0      0.6386667       50
# 10:       B    1  72   Past    72      0.0960000        0
# 11:       B    2 130   Past    58      0.1733333        0
# 12:       B    3 193   Past    63      0.2573333        0
# 13:       B    4 244   Past    51      0.3253333        0
# 14:       B    5 304 Future     0      0.4053333       60
# 15:       B    6 349 Future     0      0.4653333       45
# 16:       B    7 394 Future     0      0.5253333       45
# 17:       B    8 439 Future     0      0.5853333       45
# 18:       B    9 484 Future     0      0.6453333       45
```

You might also want to consider running your calculation in parallel by product.

Comment: This answer had a significant improvement in speed, thank you! However I would benefit greatly if it could be faster still. Additionally, when applying the modified script to my full data set, I am experiencing a peculiar issue where once the Cum has reached the TotalSales limit, the next day Forecast is a negative number equal to the total Forecast sales for all previous Future time steps. Thoughts?

Comment: How would you handle cumulative sales greater than 1500 for A? It was not mentioned in OP

Comment: Great question. We will assume that as a small company selling unique goods, we are only capable of selling the forecasted max before we run out of available products. So once we sell 1500 of Product A, the forecasted production will go to 0.